# Thread safe worker thread with this pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stdthread

I am using a `std::thread` object to perform network accesses by using values from a thread-safe queue. Is it okay, to pass the class' `this` pointer to the thread? The modbus queue is a thread-safe object, so that is not the problem.

I am just worried about the pointer access because the pointer is not thread-safe. I know I can just pass the queue object, but this is only for curiosity reasons.

I may now at the point of reading the threadCancel bool that the object is not destroyed, but after that, it may be undefined.

Is it good behaviour to lock a mutex in the Destructor?

```
std::atomic_bool modbusThreadRunning = false;
std::atomic_bool cancelThread = false;


void modbusWorkerThread(DataAcquisition* this_p) {
    //Reference to a thread safe object
    if(cancelThread){
        modbusThreadRunning = false;
        return;
    }
    std::scoped_lock lock(this_p->destroyLocker);
    auto& queue = this_p->getModbusQueue();
    
    while (this_p->getModbusQueue().count() > 0) {
        //Access values of queue and modify it
        //Without the class getting destroyed
    }
    modbusThreadRunning == false;
}


class DataAcquisition{
    std::thread* modbusThread;
    std::mutex destroyLocker;
    ts_queue<int> queue;
    void startModbusThread() {
        if (modbusThreadRunning == false)
        {
            modbusThreadRunning = true;
            modbusThread = new std::thread (modbusWorkerThread, this);
            modbusThread->detach();
        }
    }

    ts_queue<int>& getModbusQueue(){ return queue; } 

    ~DataAcquisition(){ cancelThread = true; destroyLocker.lock(); }
}
```

Comment: Why is the non-mutable *pointer* not thread safe?

Comment: @Eljay how do you know `getModbusQueue` doesn't modify `this_p` ?

Comment: `std::make_unique<std::thread>` this is bad (it works, but it is bad practice) and it indicates that you still have problems with understanding some features of C++. I would recommend you to master other C++ features, before playing with threads. Threading is hard since almost all mistakes made are quite subtle and usually manifest in none deterministic way.

Comment: @Jeffrey • Unless the OP misstated the problem, `this_p` is not modified.

Comment: Anyway you didn't provide enough data to unintended what have you done wrong (or not). Please paperer [mcve] which will show your problem.

Comment: @MarekR can you just briefly explain why, because the only thing that may free the thread pointer is the destruction of the DataAcquisition class, which is only done at application's exit()

Comment: @Jeffrey indeed getModbusQueue() returns a reference to a thread safe implementation of a std::queue

Answer (score 4):

You have not shown complete, self-contained code that shows the whole entirety of how your multiple execution threads work, so it is not possible based on the shown code to analyze whether its usage of the pointer in the new execution thread is undefined behavior or not. However: your general question can be answered authoritatively -- that there's nothing unique or special about the `this` pointer, as compared with any other pointer, when it is passed to a new execution thread in this manner.

If you pass an ordinary pointer to some object to a new execution thread the pointer remains valid as long as the referenced object exists. After the underlying object gets destroyed accessing the pointer becomes undefined behavior.

Same thing applies to the `this` pointer. After its object gets destroyed accessing the pointer, in any way, whether it's accessing its members or methods, becomes undefined behavior.

You will need to make sure that in the rest of your code, in some form or fashion, the execution thread will never accesses the passed in pointer after the underlying object gets destroyed.